# JQuery Load using MVC3 @Url.Action does not pass parameters properly

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I noticed that doing `@Url.Action("myAction", new { param1 = 123, param2 = 456})` provides me with an invalid URL `Home/myAction?param1=123&amp;param2=456`.

I am attempting to do

```
$("#myAjaxDiv").load(url);
```

But only `param1` is getting populated in the action method.

When I remove the `&amp;` and make it just `&` then it works, but doing a string replace is super hacky.

```
url = url.replace("&amp;", "&");
```

Am I missing something here?

*EDIT:* Per request I'm including some of my sample app. (you can create a new MVC app and just add these quickly and see for yourself)

Controller:

```
public ActionResult AjaxTest(int? year, int? month)
{
    ViewBag.Message = string.Format("Year: {0}, Month: {1}", year.HasValue ? year.ToString() : "no year", month.HasValue ? month.ToString() : "no month");
    return PartialView("AjaxTest");
}
```

AjaxTest View:

```
@ViewBag.Message
```

Index View:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var url="";
        $("#noParams").click(function () {
            url = "Home/AjaxTest";
            $("#ajaxy").load(url)
            $("#url").text(url);
        });
        $("#yearParam").click(function () {
            url = "Home/AjaxTest?year=2012";
            $("#ajaxy").load(url)
            $("#url").text(url);
        });
        $("#yearAndMonthParam").click(function () {
            url = "Home/AjaxTest?year=2012&month=10";
            $("#ajaxy").load(url)
            $("#url").text(url);
        });

        $("#generated").click(function () {
            url = "@(Url.Action("AjaxTest", new { year=2012, month=10}))";
            $("#ajaxy").load(url);
            $("#url").text(url);
        });

    });
</script>

<a id="noParams" href="#">No Params</a> <br />
<a id="yearParam" href="#">Year Param</a> <br />
<a id="yearAndMonthParam" href="#">Year and Month Param</a> <br />
<a id="generated" href="#">Generated</a> <br />
<div id="ajaxy">

</div>

<div>
URL: <span  id="url"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: that's weird, looks like you're not the only one ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898855/built-in-method-to-encode-ampersands-in-urls-returned-from-url-action

Comment: Can you post how do you populate your `url` parameter? I guess you are missing a `Html.Raw()` somewhere...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By default every content (which is not `IHtmlString`) emitted using a `@` block is automatically HTML encoded by Razor (see this [Razor intro article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx) Html Encoding section)

The `Url.Action` returns just a plain `string` so thats why the `&` gets encoded.

Use the `Html.Raw` if you don't want the encodeing:

```
url = "@(Html.Raw(Url.Action("AjaxTest", new { year=2012, month=10})))";
```

Comment: both of these work, but they're not as clean feeling as I'd like

Comment: @NathanKoop whether something is clean or not clean is very subjective. This is how Razor and it's encoding works... usually you don't use the `Url.Action` method directly but the `Html.BeginForm` or `Html.ActionLink` helpers which takes care of the encoding.

Comment: after thinking about it some more, it seems like the right design decision. changing the return value of `Url.Action` to a `Type` would then require consumers of it to call `.ToString()` on it when used from C# classes (as `Url.Action` can be used in both `View`s and `Class`es) ...

Answer (score 4):

You can build the url in this way also.

```
var url = "@Url.Action("AjaxTest","YourControllerName")?year=2012&month=10";
$("#ajaxy").load(url);
```

Comment: both of these work, but they're not as clean feeling as I'd like